# return 0 with sql query instead of nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I return a 0 with as Responses with the PossibleAnswerText if count is 0? Right now it won't return anything.

```
select 
    COUNT(sr.Id) AS 'Responses', qpa.PossibleAnswerText
from 
    CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.QuestionPossibleAnswer as qpa 
join  
    CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse as sr on sr.QuestionPossibleAnswerId = qpa.Id
where 
    sr.QuestionPossibleAnswerId = 116 
GROUP BY 
    qpa.PossibleAnswerText
```

Comment: if it returns nothing, then there's no records with sr.QuestionPossibleAnswerID=116

Comment: left join didn't work, already tried that.  I know there's no records, that's why I'm trying to show 0.

Comment: Which database system are you using? It may make sense to add that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `LEFT JOIN`, and remove the condition on the "rightmost" table from the `WHERE` clause;

```
SELECT COUNT(sr.Id) AS 'Responses', qpa.PossibleAnswerText
FROM CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.QuestionPossibleAnswer AS qpa 
LEFT JOIN CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse as sr 
  ON sr.QuestionPossibleAnswerId = qpa.Id
WHERE qpa.Id = 116 
GROUP BY qpa.PossibleAnswerText
```

Comment: I just want one result, the count and the text.  That query brings back multiple rows